# What is the point of useCallback in reference to useAuthProvider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dependencies, react-admin

I'm working on a project where useAuthProvider is causing a useEffect to run ever render. How do I avoid this?

```js
const authProvider = useAuthProvider();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    authProvider()
      .then((data) => {
        setRoles(data);
        setLoaded(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
}, [authProvider]);
```

Every time this hook runs authProvider is an object so the shallow compare of useEffect will always evaluate to false.

Have tried just pulling the function I need as well.

```js
const {getRoles} = useAuthProvider()
```

However the getRoles function also will always evaluate to false in the useEffect dependencies because useAuthProvider produces a a new instance of the function on every render.

Seems like it might be a good use case for useCallback. But we run into the exact same issue.

```js
const getRolesCallback = useCallback(
    () => authProvider.getRoles(),
    [authProvider]
  );
```

useCallback has the exact same dependency check where authProvider evaluates to false and therefore the useCallback refreshes the function and triggers the useEffect again.

I was looking at some of the react-admin code where they actually use useCallback in this way, but I'm not seeing how it's doing anything.

This is from /ra-core/src/auth/useGetPermissions.ts

```js
const useGetPermissions = (): GetPermissions => {
    const authProvider = useAuthProvider();
    const getPermissions = useCallback(
        (params: any = {}) => authProvider.getPermissions(params),
        [authProvider]
    );

    return authProvider ? getPermissions : getPermissionsWithoutProvider;
};
```

Won't this useCallback be useless because the authProvider dependency will evaluate to false every time? Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want it to run just on startup?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you do not need to include `authProvider` at all in your dependencies, just an empty array `[]` will do for your use case. An empty array for the dependency (2nd) parameter means the hook will just run on the initial render.

Comment: Right. I think I've just read too many articles that recommend against this practice. The issue is that this method is just trying to trick react that there are no dependencies when in reality there are. This can lead to really hard to track down bugs. https://twitter.com/kentcdodds/status/1141190707232698369?lang=en

Comment: Good point. What happens if you use `authProvider.getPermissions` as the dependency? That may be pointing to a non-generated function, which would be better suited for useCallback anyway as that is the specific property (method) being utilized.

Comment: I have to check up on this problem again as this was a while back. I think react-admin may have added something to useAuthProvider that solves this, so it doesn't trigger the useEffect every cycle. But I'll have to check on it again.